# Use text to speech in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, ssml

I'm using microsoft bot framework, C# and Visual Studio and I'm trying to get the bot to reply with speech, I'm currently working with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-text-to-speech) documentation, I have added it to my code like so:

```
[LuisIntent("GreetTheBot")]
public async Task GreetIntent(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> activity, LuisResult result)
{
    await context.SayAsync(text: "Welcome to my bot!", speak: "Welcome to my bot!");
    return;
}
```

The problem is that the bot replies with the message "Welcome to my bot" but there's no speech coming out neither in the emulator or in production, how can this be fixed so that speech actually comes out?

Comment: Any exceptions?  Check the event viewer/server logs too

Comment: No exceptions, the threat executes normally and then exits

Comment: There are no events in the event viewer?

Comment: My event log is empty as well :(

Comment: On which channel are you trying ?

Answer (score 0):

The input to the bot needs to be **via voice**, to get the response back in voice. So in emulator, you need to press the mic button next to the 'Type your message..' input box and talk in your input. Then the bot will respond back in voice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this sample should help you : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText , you can send any audio/wav file to the bot.

Comment: The link is broken